# Caching @nestjs/graphql resolver response

Tags: caching, graphql, nestjs, apollo-server

I have graphql config:

```
export const graphQLConfig: GqlModuleAsyncOptions = {
    imports: [ConfigModule],
    useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        autoSchemaFile: 'schema.graphql',
        cacheControl: {
            defaultMaxAge: 60,
            stripFormattedExtensions: false,
            calculateHttpHeaders: true.
        },
        ...
    }),
    inject: [ConfigService],
}
```

And now I want to cache my response from resolver sending large amount of data:

```
@Query(() => [ConvertRateType])
async getRates(
     @Args('input') input: GetConvertRatesInput,
): Promise<ConvertRateType[]> {
     const rates = await this._ratesService.getRates(input)
     return rates
}
```

How can I do this using @nestjs/graphql? I'm using `redis` as a storage.

Comment: what'd you end up doing to resolve the global caching with graphql? I'm working on the same issue myself